# log4j2 -version 2.5 - How to Configure log4j2 using a java.util.properties object

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to configure log4j2 version 2.5 using a properties object. Reason for doing this is migration from version 1.2.17. I cannot directly use the properties file. We do some modifications to it programmaticaly.

Here's what I have tried:

## LogTest.java

```
public class LogTest {

   static {
          System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFactory",     "logsample.common.util.LogsampleConfigurationFactory");
   }

    private static Logger logger =      LogManager.getLogger(LogTest.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        logger.debug("First log");
        logger.info("Infoed");
    }
}
```

## trace.properties

```
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = D:/rolling/rollingtest.log


appenders = file


appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFile
appender.file.fileName = ${filename}
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n


loggers = file

logger.file.name = logware.common.util
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFile
```

## LogwareConfigurationFactory.java

```
public class LogsampleConfigurationFactory extends ConfigurationFactory {

    @Override
    protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
        return new String[]{".properties", "*"};
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(ConfigurationSource source) {


        return new PropertiesConfiguration(createConfigurationSource(), null);
    }



    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(String name, URI configLocation) {
        return new PropertiesConfiguration(createConfigurationSource(), null);
    }

    private ConfigurationSource createConfigurationSource()
    {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            p.load(new  FileInputStream("D:/log4jSample/properties/trace.properties"));

            p.store(out, null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

        ConfigurationSource configSrc = null;
        try {
            configSrc = new ConfigurationSource(in);
        }
        catch (IOException i)
        {

        }
        return configSrc;
    }
}
```

When I run the LogTest class, it fails to get the LogContext with a null pointer.

## Exception Stack

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration.<init>(BuiltConfiguration.java:58)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:36)
at logware.common.util.LogwareConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(LogwareConfigurationFactory.java:46)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:427)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:256)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:561)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:578)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:214)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:235)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:167)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:522)
at logware.common.util.LogTest.<clinit>(LogTest.java:58)
```

So, its the rootComponent that I have not put in the PropertiesConfiguration constructor. But I have no idea what it should be.
Any guidance or a clue in this regard would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 2.5 I would recommend you do:

```
@Override
public Configuration getConfiguration(ConfigurationSource source) {
    PropertiesConfigurationFactory factory = new PropertiesConfigurationFactory();
    return factory.getConfiguration(source);
}
```

With the latest release you will have to modify this to do:

```
@Override
public Configuration getConfiguration(LoggerContext ctx, ConfigurationSource source) {
    PropertiesConfigurationFactory factory = new PropertiesConfigurationFactory();
    return factory.getConfiguration(ctx, source);
}
```