# How to configure log4j2 from Properties object?

Tags: java, log4j2

Can log4j2 be initialized from Properties object (no properties file)? This was supported in old log4j 1.2.x (see code below), but I didn't find how to implement this with new log4j2.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
// ...set some properties
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking on the [Apache Log4J 2 Documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) website?

There's the GitHub [apache / logging-log4j2](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2) where you have a section detailing the [Usage](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2#usage) with code snippets.

Please, keep in mind the security vulnerabilities issues discovered in Log4j 2. Recommended you upgrade to Log4j 2.3.1 (for Java 6), 2.12.3 (for Java 7), or 2.17.0 (for Java 8 and later). As recommended also in ***Apache Log4j 2*** website.
There are also answers on ***StackOverflow*** like this one [log4j2 -version 2.5 - How to Configure log4j2 using a java.util.properties object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846838/log4j2-version-2-5-how-to-configure-log4j2-using-a-java-util-properties-objec)

Comment: Yes, I checked log4j's website before asking here. The GitHub page covers only very basic usage of log4j2.

Comment: The answer on StackOverflow that I added doesn't help you? In version 2.5 you need to use Properties Configuration with Factory pattern, i.e. `PropertiesConfigurationFactory` and for a later version, you should modify the code as shown in the answer (it worked for me)